# How to have a procedure continue onto the next conditional statement regardless of whether its true or false

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do the following:

1. Check whether the first condition is true
2. If the first condition is true, I want the stored procedure insert 1 entry into calculation depending on the value of the 1st 'form_field_id' taken from my cursor
3. Then I want unlimited entries (based on whats in the loop) into value and `calculation_value` correlated to the 1st `form_field_id`
4. Check whether the second condition is true
5. If the second condition is true, I want unlimited entries into `calculation_value` and value  based off whats in the loop (with different values correlated to the 2nd `form_field_id`)
6. If the first condition is false, I want to have the stored procedure go on to the second condition and check whether its true or false.
7. If both of the conditions are false, I want the stored procedure to not do anything

Below is my attempt thus far. The stored procedure compiles just fine but doesn't do what I am trying to do listed above:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROC IS
  Cursor c1 is
 select 
       SUM(Value_Tx) as sum_of_values
       , ff.FORM_FIELD_ID
             from value v
             join submission_Value sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
             join form_field ff on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
            where VALUE_TX NOT LIKE '%-%' AND VALUE_TX NOT LIKE '%:%' AND     VALUE_TX NOT LIKE '%.%'
          and ff.form_field_id in  (1,6)
     group by  ff.form_field_id;
 l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
 v_value_id value.value_id%type;
 v_calculation_id calculation.calculation_id%type;
BEGIN
 OPEN c1;
 IF l_var.form_field_id = 6
 THEN
 insert into calculation (calculation_id, Calculation_Arguments_Tx)
                  values (null, 'SUM_NET_GEN');
LOOP
   FETCH c1 into l_var;
   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      insert into value (value_id, value_tx, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code)
                     values (null, l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.data_date, 'UTC0', null, null, 'NA')
                     returning value_id into v_value_id;
      insert into calculation_value(calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id)
                                values (null, v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.form_field_id);
       END LOOP;
 ELSIF l_var.form_field_Id = 1
 THEN
 insert into calculation (calculation_id,Calculation_Arguments_Tx)
                  values (null, 'SUM_DEMAND')
                  returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
      LOOP
   FETCH c1 into l_var;
   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      insert into value (value_id,  value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code)
                     values (null,  l_var.sum_of_values, 0, l_var.data_date, 'UTC0', null, null, 'NA')
                     returning value_id into v_value_id;
      insert into calculation_value ( calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id)
                                values (null, v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.form_field_id);
      END LOOP;
  END IF;

   CLOSE c1;
END TEST_PROC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the cursor into `l_var` before you check the value of `form_field_id`. I suggest rewriting your procedure as:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROC IS
  Cursor c1 is
    select SUM(Value_Tx) as sum_of_values,
           ff.FORM_FIELD_ID
      from value v
      join submission_Value sv
        on v.value_id = sv.value_id
      join form_field ff
        on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
      where VALUE_TX NOT LIKE '%-%' AND
            VALUE_TX NOT LIKE '%:%' AND
            VALUE_TX NOT LIKE '%.%' and
            ff.form_field_id in  (1,6)
      group by  ff.form_field_id;

  l_var            c1%ROWTYPE;
  v_value_id       value.value_id%type;
  v_calculation_id calculation.calculation_id%type;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  FETCH c1 into l_var;

  IF NOT c1%NOTFOUND AND l_var.form_field_id = 6 THEN
    insert into calculation
      (calculation_id, Calculation_Arguments_Tx)
    values
      (null, 'SUM_NET_GEN');

    LOOP
      FETCH c1 into l_var;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

      insert into value
        (value_id, value_tx, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code)
      values
        (null, l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.data_date, 'UTC0', null, null, 'NA')
      returning value_id into v_value_id;

      insert into calculation_value
        (calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id)
      values 
        (null, v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.form_field_id);
    END LOOP;
  ELSIF NOT c1%NOTFOUND AND l_var.form_field_Id = 1 THEN
    insert into calculation
      (calculation_id,Calculation_Arguments_Tx)
    values
      (null, 'SUM_DEMAND')
    returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;

    LOOP
      FETCH c1 into l_var;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

      insert into value
        (value_id,  value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code)
      values
        (null,  l_var.sum_of_values, 0, l_var.data_date, 'UTC0', null, null, 'NA')
      returning value_id into v_value_id;

      insert into calculation_value
        (calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id)
      values
        (null, v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.form_field_id);
    END LOOP;
  END IF;

  CLOSE c1;
END TEST_PROC;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: for some reason, nothing is being inserted into calculation_value and value. are we supposed to FETCH twice? I don't think i need a fetch before the first insert since im not using anything from the cursor in that insert statement... (correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: to add onto before, i am only doing this with a single row being returned in my cursor currently

Comment: To reply to your first comment, in the first `IF` statement following the opening of the cursor you have `IF l_var.form_field_id = 6`. At this point you've opened the cursor but you have never fetched anything, and all the fields in `l_var` are NULL. I took this to be a simple logic error, and that the cursor had to be fetched so that values were available.

Comment: ah ok thanks, so how do you suggest i proceed? should i just create two separate procedures looking for the two IDs / loading them separately? Is there no way to integrate them? I wasn't able to find a way to fetch a value for the conditional statement (IF)  and then also fetch the same line / entry to insert